# Passing data from one Fragment to another | Change content of ViewPager Fragment (inside ViewPager)

Tags: android, replace, android-viewpager, fragment

I develop an application, which should help me to manage my finances. So now I've got a TabLayout, which is connected to a ViewPager. The adapter for this ViewPager looks like this:

```
    package de.financeplanner.util.adapter.pager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import de.financeplanner.fragment.BaseListFragment;

/**
 * Dient als Adapter für den ViewPager
 * Diese Klasse wird an ein TabLayout gebunden um so bei einem
 * Tabwechsel den ViewPager zu updaten.
 * Created by Christian on 20.01.2017.
 */

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private static final int PAGE_COUNT = 4;

    private final String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Übersicht", "Einnahmen", "Ausgaben", "Kategorie" };

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        BaseListFragment fragment = new BaseListFragment();
        Bundle startCondition = new Bundle();
        final String arg = "startCondition";
        switch(position){
            case PagerTabConstants.OVERVIEW:  startCondition.putInt(arg, PagerTabConstants.OVERVIEW);
                            break;
            case PagerTabConstants.REVENUES:  startCondition.putInt(arg, PagerTabConstants.REVENUES);
                            break;
            case PagerTabConstants.EXPENSES:  startCondition.putInt(arg, PagerTabConstants.EXPENSES);
                            break;
            case PagerTabConstants.CATEGORY:  startCondition.putInt(arg, PagerTabConstants.CATEGORY);
                            break;
        }
        fragment.setArguments(startCondition);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

}
```

Now, you can click inside the BaseListFragment on an Item, then a new Fragment should be loaded and the data from the clicked Item should be passed to the new Fragment. 
And here is my problem. I know, how I can pass data to a fragment, but how can I replace the old Fragment with the new Fragment? Because the Fragment inside the Tab is loaded by the FragmentPagerAdapter. 
For better understanding, I've got this image for you:

[image: MainActivity TabLayout]

Answer (score 0):

when you click on a button in  your existing fragment, call a method inside your main activity that can replace your fragment for you.

```
MainActivity parentActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
parentActivity.changeFragment();
```

Then call your changeFragment method in your MainActivity that can change your fragment, or replace it.

Comment: Yeah ok, but the main problem is, that my FragmentPagerAdapter handle the fragment replacing. When I want to replace a fragent manually, I need a container Id and I've got no container ID, because the FragmentPagerAdapter handles this for me...